# slow training with GPU google cloud ML engine

Tags: python, tensorflow, file-io, google-cloud-ml, bytesio

sorry if my question is so dump but i spent a lot of time trying to understand the reason of the problem but i couldn't 
so here it is

i'm training tacotron model on google cloud ML i have trained it before on floyd hub and it was pretty fast so i configured my project to be able to run on google ML

this is the major changes that i made to my project

**original**

```py
with open(metadata_filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
  self._metadata = [line.strip().split('|') for line in f]
  hours = sum((int(x[2]) for x in self._metadata)) * hparams.frame_shift_ms / (3600 * 1000)
  log('Loaded metadata for %d examples (%.2f hours)' % (len(self._metadata), hours))
```

**my config**

```py
with file_io.FileIO(metadata_filename, 'r') as f:
     self._metadata = [line.strip().split('|') for line in f]
     hours = sum((int(x[2]) for x in self._metadata)) * hparams.frame_shift_ms / (3600 * 1000)
     log('Loaded metadata for %d examples (%.2f hours)' % (len(self._metadata), hours))
```

**original**

```py
def _get_next_example(self):
    '''Loads a single example (input, mel_target, linear_target, cost) from disk'''
    if self._offset >= len(self._metadata):
      self._offset = 0
      random.shuffle(self._metadata)
    meta = self._metadata[self._offset]
    self._offset += 1

    text = meta[3]
    if self._cmudict and random.random() < _p_cmudict:
      text = ' '.join([self._maybe_get_arpabet(word) for word in text.split(' ')])

    input_data = np.asarray(text_to_sequence(text, self._cleaner_names), dtype=np.int32)
    linear_target = np.load(os.path.join(self._datadir, meta[0]))
    mel_target = np.load(os.path.join(self._datadir, meta[1]))
    return (input_data, mel_target, linear_target, len(linear_target))
```

**my config**

```py
 def _get_next_example(self):

    '''Loads a single example (input, mel_target, linear_target, cost) from disk'''
    if self._offset >= len(self._metadata):
        self._offset = 0
        random.shuffle(self._metadata)
    meta = self._metadata[self._offset]
    self._offset += 1

    text = meta[3]
    if self._cmudict and random.random() < _p_cmudict:
        text = ' '.join([self._maybe_get_arpabet(word) for word in text.split(' ')])

    input_data = np.asarray(text_to_sequence(text, self._cleaner_names), dtype=np.int32)
    f = BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(
        os.path.join(self._datadir, meta[0]),binary_mode=True))
    linear_target = np.load(f)
    s = BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(
        os.path.join(self._datadir, meta[1]),binary_mode = True))
    mel_target = np.load(s)
    return (input_data, mel_target, linear_target, len(linear_target))
```

here 2 screen shots to show the difference 
[Google ML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Nk1.png),[FLoydhub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rxQ0.png)

and this is the training command i use in google ML i use scale-tier=BASIC_GPU

`gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training "$JOB_NAME"      --stream-logs     --module-name trainier.train     --package-path trainier     --staging-bucket "$BUCKET_NAME"     --region "us-central1"    --scale-tier=basic-gpu     --config ~/gp-master/config.yaml     --runtime-version=1.4    --     --base_dir "$BASEE_DIR"     --input "$TRAIN_DATA"`

So my question is did i do something that could cause this slow reading data maybe or there is problem in google cloud ML and i doubt that ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well i figured it out i should have put tensorflow-gpu==1.4 in required packages not tensorflow==1.4 ^^

Comment: This is so easy to overlook, I've been smashing my head for days trying to figure out why the GPU didn't work in the cloud! Thanks for sharing!! please mark this answer as accepted to that the question is complete.